# Hibernate: Gradle Ant cannot find hibernate.reveng.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am creating a task for generating java classes from the database. I created a gradle task using ant. The strange this is that the task is expecting a hibernate.cfg.xml file for `revengfile` property.

This is my gradle task:

```
task hibernate{
   description "Generates Java Classes from the Database Schema."
   group "Hibernate"

   doLast{
    ant {
        def base = "$projectDir/src/main/java"

        taskdef(name: 'hibernatetool', 
            classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask', 
            classpath: configurations.compile.asPath )

        hibernatetool( destdir : "$base" ) { 

            jdbcconfiguration(
                propertyfile:"src/main/resources/hibernate.properties", revengfile:"src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml", //expects hibernate.cfg.xml instead
                packagename: springProperties["hibernate.generate.package"], detectmanytomany:"true" ) 

            hbm2java(ejb3:true)
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

The `revengfile` property overrides `propertyfile`. I checked the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html), there is an example with `hibernate.reveng.xml`, but it actually only works with `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

This is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration 
    SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3308/db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pw</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
    </session-factory>

  </hibernate-configuration>
```

My `hibernate.reveng.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering
    SYSTEM "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>

   <schema-selection match-catalog=".*" match-schema=".*" match-table=".*" />

   <table schema="db" name="string" class="StringEntity"></table> 

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems to be a bug, since the `revengfile` should expect a `hibernate.reveng.xml` instead of an `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. For anyone who encounters a similar issue I found an alternative solution to customize the configuration for reverse engineering. The `reversestrategy` property in `jdbcconfiguration`  expects a class that extends `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy`.

This is my Java implementation for reverse engineering:

```
public class HibernateReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

public HibernateReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
    super(delegate);
}

@Override
public String tableToClassName(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {
    return super.tableToClassName(tableIdentifier) + "Entity";
}

}
```

And this is my gradle ant task:

```
task hibernate{
description "Generates Java Classes from the Database Schema."
group "Hibernate"

doLast{
    ant {
        def base = "$projectDir/src/main/java"

        taskdef(name: 'hibernatetool', 
            classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
            classpath: configurations.compile.asPath )

        hibernatetool( destdir : "$base") { 

            // needs to be specified in order to find the java class
            classpath{
                path(location:"${buildDir}/classes/java/main/")
            }

            jdbcconfiguration(
                propertyfile:"src/main/resources/hibernate.properties", 
                reversestrategy:"mypackage.HibernateReverseEngineeringStrategy",
                packagename: springProperties["hibernate.generate.package"]
            ) 

            hbm2java(ejb3:true)
        } 
    }
}

}
```